# Getting Exception: Element is not clickable because another element obscures it

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
package Roughpack;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Executabel\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        driver.get("http://pro.tykitksa.com/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> dropDownList = driver.findElements(By.id("user_event_city"));

        System.out.println(dropDownList.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < dropDownList.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(dropDownList.get(i).getText());

            WebElement Dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("user_event_city"));

            Select select = new Select(Dropdown);

            select.selectByIndex(4);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add wait for cityModal webelement, because on page load your dropdown is nit visible:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Executabel\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    driver.get("http://pro.tykitksa.com/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//this is wait for se-pre-con-home element will be invisible        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"se-pre-con-home\"]")))); 

    List<WebElement> dropDownList = driver.findElements(By.id("user_event_city"));

    System.out.println(dropDownList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < dropDownList.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(dropDownList.get(i).getText());

        WebElement Dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("user_event_city"));

        Select select = new Select(Dropdown);

        select.selectByIndex(4);
```

Comment: But all the dropdown list is shown on the console
System.out.println(dropDownList.get(i).getText());

Comment: it's in your browser when page is already opened, but when you start webdriver your page looks like https://prnt.sc/k53yg8 then like https://prnt.sc/k53yje -> https://prnt.sc/k53yje, so you need to wait for cityModal element

Comment: Got the same exception Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <select id="user_event_city" class="user-city select_user_city" name="user_city"> is not clickable at point (951.5,508.9666748046875) because another element <div class="se-pre-con-home"> obscures it

Comment: @MyTesting_Account look now to solution and try again please, I edit wait

Comment: @ Sergiy Konoplyaniy Thanks mate Now its work fine....

Comment: great, if so please accept my answer